# How properly SELECT several one-to-many rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

We have 3 tables.

1) **Order**

PK

order_id

2) **Order_Products**

PK | FK | Column | Column

order_product_id | order_id | product_id | name | quantity

3) **Order_Product_Components**

PK | FK | Column | Column | Column

order_product_component_id | order_product_id | stock_id | name | quantity

---

Tables 2 and 3 have one-to-many relationship.

So if we want to get an array of order products with their components what is the best query we can use?

Finally the result should be this format (if we have just 1 product with 2 components):

```
$products = array(
     array(
    '    'product_id' => x,
         'name'       => x,
         'quantity'   => x,
         'stocks'     => array(
              array(
                   'stock_id' => x,
                   'name'     => x,
                   'quantity' => x),
              array(
                   'stock_id' => x,
                   'name'     => x,
                   'quantity' => x)));
```

Comment: MySQL, as far as I know, will return an array of ONE row. I don't think there is any way to do a nested array. You need to retrieve the data with multiple queries and build the result in code.

Comment: just fyi, you cant pull a multidimentional array out of sql with 1 query. you'll need 1 for the order data, and 1 for the items attached to the order.

Comment: I understand that. So my question was what is the best way to do that? Grouping, joining, ... ?

Comment: Order is a reserved word. We're off to a bad start.

Answer (score 0):

Since order is a reserved word I have changed the order table name to 'orders'. I am using join to get the expected results.  I think group by would not be as useful to get the result the way you want it.

```
 $sql= "select * from orders o join order_products op on o.order_id=op.order_id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $orders =$stmt->fetchAll();


    foreach($orders as $o){
    $sql= "select stock_id,name,quantity from  order_products op 
           join order_product_components opc on opc.order_product_id=op.order_product_id where op.order_product_id=:orderprodid";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array('orderprodid'=>$o['order_product_id']));
    $comps =$stmt->fetchAll();
     $o['stocks']=$comps;
    }
```

Comment: Unless Kamil actually needs other unspecified data from it, the references to `order[s]` table is not needed. Just using `WHERE op.order_id` should be enough and would reduce the number of joins.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to do a loop of queries, which can be very expensive.

Just do a query joining all tables and order by product id,product name, ... stock id, stock name,... and loop through the results and build your array in one pass.